# Why is reachabilityForInternetConnection not working after I remove internet connection after launching the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

```
+ (BOOL) networkAvailable {
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I am using Tony Million's Reachability class. I have made a static utility method to check for current reachability. however it only works for the first time when app is launched.

If I remove the LAN cable from my iMac (I am connected to my office's shared LAN) after starting the app in the simulator,

this method still returns YES.

Also, Same behaviour happens when I test it with the device and remove the wifi connection and try making an API call.

It never detects that internet is no more available.

I don't want any notification of reachability changing. I just want to be able to check if the connection is available before making an API call.

**EDIT:**
This is how I use it.

```
if(![MyUtilities networkAvailable])
{
   // network not there. show a message.
}
else {
  // make the API call
}
```

Comment: Tony Million's Reachability class depends totally on reachability notification method. Checking just before making a call is not very scalable and hence the notification mechanism in used. This involves operating systems optimisation and hence better to use. Why can you just use a boolean, which will be changed accordingly in the notifiers selector and in your API call just check using this boolean. This is not so different you see. Also let me know why you are against this method?

Comment: btw reachabilityForInternetConnection is checking for zero address not being there. is it sufficient ?

or should we check for a hostname or some DNS instead?

Comment: How did you make the call?As an instance method the code works fine when testing wifi connection turn on and off.Show us the class initialization and how you called this method

Comment: @LithuT.V: Added. It is a class method.